# Use of double quotes in a 'input type="text"' value wont work, string stops at double-quote !

Tags: php, javascript, html

How can I make it possible for users to use the '"' (double quote) inside a textfield...

Whenever I do use double-quote in the field (the value) then when receiving the variable in my PHP file with:

```
   $text=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']);
```

and then echo it, I get a string which is escaped properly, but the string stops exactly before the double-quote!

I dont want it to stop because of the double-quote though!

Javascript is used to validate the text-field so its not empty, maybe I should do something more with javascript when validating, and altering the value, so php can get the correct value including the double quotes?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

CODE:

```
   $headline= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['headline']);
   echo htmlentities($headline);
```

I have tried merging the two above, will only give the same results.
NOTE: I have ALSO TRIED adding `ENT_QUOTES` into the htmlentities function...

Unformatted string as entered:

```
   + , . ; : - _ space & % ! ? = # * ½ @ / \ [ ]< > " ' hej hej
```

will output this when echoing it:

```
   + , . ; : - _ space & % ! ? = # * Â½ @ / \\ [ ]< >
```

Comment: Please don't use JavaScript for this. It would do nothing you shouldn't be doing on the server-side anyway.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to use `htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES)` or `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES)` to convert the quotes to the HTML entity `&quot;`. Those function also take care of other characters that should be encoded.

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is only meant for escaping single quotes in database queries, so that you can correctly enter strings with single quotes into your database (and avoid SQL injections).

EDIT: Added parameters. Thanks to micahwittman

Comment: It wont display a double-quote, it only displays backslashes... Read my update plz

Comment: You need to use the optional second parameter for htmlentities like this: echo htmlentities($headline, ENT_QUOTES); which will also encode double and single quotes (see other special constants besides ENT_QUOTES at http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php ). Also, you shouldn't only use sql_real_escape_string() for preparing to store the string in a mysql database - that's why \ is becoming \\.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it isn't working when you're outputting it into the `input` is because the `value` is being truncated at the quote. You'll need to use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on the output.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up two things: `mysql_real_escape_string` is used to prepare strings for storing in a mysql database. `htmlentities` is used to prepare strings for echoing in the browser. Both are important to do, but calling one after the other on the same string can't be expected to work. Do something like the following:

```
// Copy string after escaping for mysql into $db_headline
$db_headline= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['headline']);

// Copy string after escaping for page display into $html_headline
$html_headline = htmlentities($_POST['headline']);

// Store the headline in the database

...

?>
<input type="text" name="headline" value="<?php echo $html_headline ?>" />

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not the job of the JS to modify the input string, server should make sure it can accept what its getting regardless.

You could escape out the double quotes with another value either Assci symbol or HTML `&quot;` etc. before you pass it into your mysql escape function?