# PHP How to I make my textinput accept single quote or Double quotes

Tags: php, javascript

How do I make my textinput accept apostrophe or double quotes?

Everytime a user type's in this one: John's Birthday, I store this one in the database using mysql_real_escape_string().

What I wanted to do in here is to retrieve it in my text input.
I tried this one

```
<input type='text' name='title' value='<?php echo $values->title; ?>' />
```

The problem here is it removes the single quote and the letters that comes after the quote. 
I tried to changed the `value= ''` from `value=""` but what if a user types a word that has example this one:
"You and Me". The problem is still in there.

I was thinking to use str_replace in doing this one and replace the ' into `, but again I was thinking that maybe there's an easy way to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771798/use-of-double-quotes-in-a-input-type-text-value-wont-work-string-stops-at-do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this: http://www.primitivetype.com/articles/quotes_inputs.php

Basically, call [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on your output before placing it in the form's value. This will turn characters like `'` into the html equivalent `&#39;`.

e.g.

```
<input ... value='<?php echo htmlentities($values->title, ENT_QUOTES); ?>' />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace double quotes with `&quot;`. `&#39;` for single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Replace single quote with `&#145;`