# html safe input value

Tags: php, html

I am trying to place a string into a hidden html input field in the following way.

```
$str = "HBO's hit series a game of thrones...'";

echo "<input type='hidden' value='$str' />";
```

The problem is that this will return something like...

```
<input type="hidden" value="HBO" s hit series a game of thrones.../>
```

I don't want to use `urlencode()` or `mysql_escape_string` as they aren't the appropriate functions to use, what is the correct function to use for something like this?

Comment: [`htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP How to I make my textinput accept single quote or Double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591410/php-how-to-i-make-my-textinput-accept-single-quote-or-double-quotes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set HTML value attribute (with spaces) using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078192/how-to-set-html-value-attribute-with-spaces-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be changing the single quotes to double quotes

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="$str" />';
```

Comment: ...Until `$str = "HBO's hit series \"A Game of Thrones\"...";` occurs.

Comment: wel like I said it was a quick solution otherwise you should use like @Michael Berkowski  said htmlentities()